# VS2022 Cannot Create Azure Functions Project

Tags: azure-functions, visual-studio-2022

If I try to create an Azure Functions Project (Solution->Add->New Project) I get a new project folder that is completely empty, and a status message in the statusbar that says the project was created successfully.

I've already done a VS Update to 17.1.1 which didn't change anything, then did a complete repair of VS2022 from the VSInstaller.  I also reinsalled the Azure Functions Core Tools v4 with `npm i -g azure-functions-core-tools@4 --unsafe-perm true`.

I've tried creating both a net6 and net6 isolated function (timer trigger), but only the empty folder is ever created with no errors shown.

I suppose my alternative at this point is to just manually create/copy a project file and try to go from there.

[image]

Current VisualStudio2022 Installation Info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022
Version 17.1.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.1+32228.430
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Professional

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.358.51495
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.1.358.51495
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Node.js Tools   1.5.40105.1 Commit Hash:1822ee94b29c6cf748a19825f14cc26d30b0b871
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b810a05b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62201.12090
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firstly, tried to create the Azure Functions Timer Trigger with Visual Studio 2022 Community Version 17.1.1 and created successfully:**

[image]

**Also tried in the Visual Studio 2022 Professional Version 17.1.1:**
[image]

[image]

***Below is the installed Visual Studio Professional 2022 Version Product Info:***

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (2)
Version 17.1.1
VisualStudio.17.Release/17.1.1+32228.430
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.8.04161

Installed Version: Professional

.NET Core Debugging with WSL   1.0
.NET Core Debugging with WSL

ADL Tools Service Provider   1.0
This package contains services used by Data Lake tools

ASA Service Provider   1.0

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2019   17.1.358.51495
For additional information, visit https://www.asp.net/

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   17.1.358.51495
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio

Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools   17.1.358.51495
Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools

Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio   2.6.5000.0
Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Tools for Visual Studio

C# Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   17.0.21344.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Fabric.DiagnosticEvents   1.0
Fabric Diagnostic Events

Microsoft Azure Hive Query Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Hive query

Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio   17.0
Microsoft Azure Service Fabric Tools for Visual Studio

Microsoft Azure Stream Analytics Language Service   2.6.5000.0
Language service for Azure Stream Analytics

Microsoft Azure Tools for Visual Studio   2.9
Support for Azure Cloud Services projects

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft Library Manager   2.1.161+abc97ecc7d.RR
Install client-side libraries easily to any web project

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.2
Develop, run, validate your ASP.NET Core applications in the target environment. F5 your application directly into a container with debugging, or CTRL + F5 to edit & refresh your app without having to rebuild the container.

Node.js Tools   1.5.40105.1 Commit Hash:1822ee94b29c6cf748a19825f14cc26d30b0b871
Adds support for developing and debugging Node.js apps in Visual Studio

NuGet Package Manager   6.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio   17.0.32009.00
Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio

Python - Profiling support   17.0.21344.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python with Pylance   17.0.21344.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Razor (ASP.NET Core)   17.0.0.2206201+62a2c1d6162f828801565a7ca26d9d48b810a05b
Provides languages services for ASP.NET Core Razor.

SQL Server Data Tools   17.0.62201.12090
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

Syntax Visualizer   1.0
An extension for visualizing Roslyn SyntaxTrees.

ToolWindowHostedEditor   1.0
Hosting json editor into a tool window

TypeScript Tools   17.0.1229.2001
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   4.1.0-5.22109.6+0c82c4114a4e4b8b723b915eee3b13261db6717f
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual F# Tools   17.1.0-beta.21610.4+07b5673e4f2fa7630e78abe37f16b372353a7242
Microsoft Visual F# Tools

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Container Tools Extensions   1.0
View, manage, and diagnose containers within Visual Studio.

Visual Studio IntelliCode   2.2
AI-assisted development for Visual Studio.

Visual Studio Tools for Containers   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for Containers

Workflow Manager Tools 1.0   1.0
This package contains the necessary Visual Studio integration components for Workflow Manager.
```

**Note:**

**1. Re-install the .NET 6 SDK and the Runtime Package**

**2. Restart the System and try creating the new Azure Functions Project from Visual Studio 2022 Professional.**

#### Updated Answer:

Go to Visual Studio Professional 2022 > Tools > Select **Get Tools and Features**

Uninstall the Azure Development feature from that Catalogue and Re-install it, as shown below:

[image: VS Tools & Features]

Comment: Reinstalled the same (current) version of Net6 SDK - no joy.  Since I CAN create a class library project etc., I think it's more related to Functions core tools or their project templates.  Cross-posted in their repo https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2978

Comment: Recently For me, When I opened Multiple Visual Studio Windows and I tried to create a new project in New Visual Studio, I got this kind of error in Azure Functions only - it will create and show project creation successful but it doesn't show any project files in the folder as well as in Visual Studio. I got this error in Visual Studio 2022 17.0.6 Version. I updated the version, closed all the instances, restarted the system, and tried to create a new Azure Functions Project, then onwards I didn't face any issues.

Comment: If you too have multiple instances of VS, could you please close them, open the VS freshly and check once!

Comment: I restarted, opened only 1 instance of VS2022, and still cannot create a project.  Again, the folder is created in the filesystem, but there is nothing in it and nothing shows in VisualStudio SolutionExplorer either.

Comment: Any replies that people take time to try and help are helpful, so I appreciate all your effort, but it has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 19):

I finally ended up deleting the following folder:

> C:\Users\YOURUSER\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools

Visual Studio uses the files in the folder to get the last version of Azure Functions Tools. If you remove the folder, once you open Visual Studio again, it regenerates that folder and then your Visual Studio is able to get the Azure Function workers

Comment: The .NET 7 option for Azure Functions was missing, and this was the only thing that worked for me. It actually downgraded (old releases included up to 4.29, new folder is 4.18) but now the option exists.

Comment: This cleared up a ton of issues I was having launching Azure Functions in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: I have been looking all over the place for an answer to the question: Why I could not see .net 7 isolated as an option in the Azure Functions template. Ialready installed .net7 SDK.

Comment: This is also the solution to  "Visual Studio 2022 does not create an Azure Function project after completing the New Project dialog."

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue using Visual Studio 2022 Professional. I wasn't able to create an Azure Function v4 (.NET 6) and tried the following workarounds from the previous answers without success:

- Reinstalled the Azure Functions Core Tools v4
- Reinstalled .NET SDK and Azure SDK
- Several computer and Visual Studio restarts

After several actions I was able to make it works again  but I don't know which action was important.

I listed below all significant actions in the order I did them. Maybe that will help someone fixing this annoying issue !

## Check Azure credentials status

I checked that my Azure Credentials were still valid. They weren't, I had to refresh them.
In Visual Studio, go to **Help** > **Register Visual Studio** dialog, you will see if it's ok.

Screenshot was taken after credential refresh:

[image: Visual Studio account settings screenshot]

## Run a function created by a colleague

Since I wasn't able to create a new Azure Function inside VS 2022 Pro, I asked a colleague to create one for me to see if I was able to run it locally.

I was able to run the function my colleague created (debug in VS 2022)

## Try Visual Studio 2019

I still have Visual Studio 2019 installed and I had the idea to try creating a Function here.

I was able to create a new Azure Function in an empty solution using Visual Studio 2019

## Try again using Visual Studio 2022

It worked in VS 2019, it's time to try again in Visual Studio 2022.

I was finally able to create an Azure Function project in VS 2022

As I said earlier, I don't know which action unblocked the issue. Hope it can help someone else struggling with this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Checking Azure Credentials and logging back in solved it for me.

Comment: This is insane, it worked for me.